# .so Libraries and Java JNI

Tags: java, c++, c, linux, 64-bit

I dig deep - I mean very deep - into the linker and loader domain. Since the resulting work aims totally at Java, I need to know what actually happens when I compile a C program into a so library and load it in the JVM.

In the end a so library is a assembly program with symbols that gets loaded into ram, the exported symbols are taken to a special symbol table (or a dedicated one). The rest of the symbols and the library itself gets relocated.

Is that correct?

Comment: The last step, although possible, isn't necessarily common. Usually, shared libraries are generated using PIC (position independent) code that can run on from any load address without relocation.

Comment: Well that makes sense. My problem is relocating existing code (and linking it in memory) on load time. So I need the external offsets for the methods. One idea would be generating a C method which references all interesting offsets of a library and check what the java loading process did to it meaning where those pointers actual point to and use this information for the linking process. 

But I hope there are means of dynamic lookup.